# Toast primeng not displaying after making an api call

Tags: angular, primeng, toast

I have a problem when I call service message of primeng (to display a toast) in a subscribe and at the first click the toast does not appear (*however the value of the subscribe I see it in console.log ()*) and it is on the second click that the toast is displayed with the value of the subscribe.
I do not see where the problem comes from and how to solve it ....

I tried to change the detection strategy to 'onPush' or put the ngZone, but neither works for me ...

Does anyone have an idea? please

here is my code :

```
 this.sub = this.donnFacade.getError().subscribe(value => {
    if (value !== null) {
     console.log('value getError ==>', value);
      this.message = {
        key: 'erreurServerForm',
        severity: 'error',
        summary: 'Erreur serveur - Création interrompue',
        detail: `${value.status}`,
        sticky: true
      };
      this.messageService.add(this.message);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Do you have `<p-toast></p-toast>` in your HTML component ? If you try to display a toast from `ngOnInit()`, is it okay ?

Comment: @Antikhippe yes, I have a tag <p-toast></p-toast> in my HTML component. And if I try to display a toast except to subscribe, the toast is display but not in subscribe.

Comment: Do your have the trace of your subscribe in the console ? Can you create a StackBlitz ?